# What is the problem with my highcharts code?

Tags: highcharts

```
        Highcharts.chart('course', {
  chart: {
    type: 'variablepie'
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Countries compared by population density and total area.'
  },
  tooltip: {
    headerFormat: '',
    pointFormat: '<span style="color:{point.color}">\u25CF</span> <b> {point.name}</b><br/>' +
     'Population density (people per square km): <b>{point.y}</b><br/>'
  },
  series: [{
    minPointSize: 10,
    innerSize: '20%',
    zMin: 0,
    name: 'countries',
    data: [{
      name: 'C',
      y: 7000
    },{
      name: 'A',
      y: 5000
    },{
      name: 'B',
      y: 2000
    }, {
      name: 'D',
      y: 4000
    }]
  }]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, after the edit made by @Adrian Mole - nothing.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/8xzrdLva/

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
   ...
});
```

I encourage to use online editors which autocorrections could help you to see the wrong parts of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Your chart is working fine, you're probably simply missing the following script:

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/variable-pie.js"></script>
```

You can see the [highcharts variable pie example on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/variable-radius-pie/).